# wired variable are null in zk controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, controller, null, zk

I'm developing with  zk framework in java  (with eclipse ) .
I'm trying  to link some textbox (view) to 
controller throught wired variable .
The problem is that in the controller the wired variable is null when the submit event is called .
Index:[Index.zul](http://pastebin.com/caDZq2pV)
Login :[Login.java](http://pastebin.com/aujTjhHy)

Comment: Can you post the code for how you are actually accessing the variables and getting null?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Btw3Svg1 in submit event i put a null control . and the condition is true.

Answer (score 1):

In your **doAfterCompose** method add this line or you can use **doAfterCompose** method like 
this

```
 @AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view){
Selectors.wireComponents(view, this, false);
    }
```

Comment: He extends from `Selectorcomposer` so this should be done by zk. If this solution works, then there is a bug in zk.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CSS selectors in the `@Wire` parameter, just use the ZK component id. That is to say, leave off the `#`.

Also, if the Java variable name is the same as the ZK component id (eg "win") you can leave off the `@Wire` parameter all together and it'll still work fine.

Edit:
There is another problem in your code. The `Textbox` you're importing is from the POI package =X

Comment: No no, sorry, keep the `@Wire` annotation but either leave off the `#` in the parameter value (eg `@Wire("win")`) or remove the parameter all together (eg `@Wire`).

Comment: I edited my response, you're importing the wrong `Textbox` class.

Comment: Just write `@Wire Class id`. So in your case `@Wire Window win`. You will have the fewest issues that way. And of course add the access type you like.

Comment: Thank you ,now work :)  the problem is that i put in one line @wire and in another line the variable .